# Filtering events with #keys didn't work using StarkNet

Tags: blockchain, starknet

I'm trying to filter the events emmited by my contract `0x028a88bc21629b0f740b99046dbd096674e4cf89545efa6a6cd20b3e64ebb94c` which is in starknet goreli ([link](https://testnet.starkscan.co/contract/0x028a88bc21629b0f740b99046dbd096674e4cf89545efa6a6cd20b3e64ebb94c#overview)).

Now when I'm trying to filter the events with the indexed fields it's giving me *all the events* with that `event name` i.e it's not filtering with the indexed fields (keys) like its supposed to.

So, the event, which looks like this in cairo.

```
#[derive(Drop, starknet::Event)]
    struct ERC1155CollectionLaunch {
        #[key]
        tokenId: felt252,
        #[key]
        creator: ContractAddress,
        initialSupply: felt252
    }
```

When I’m filtering through the events from my RPC node with `starknet_getEvents` like this:

```
const keyFilter = [num.toHex(hash.starknetKeccak('ERC1155CollectionLaunch')), num.toHex("3"), "0x2dc934022ca93a0465a08bde434d979bac60fc3fcb07cf4d0b8d5c0af8cf442"];

        const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {accept: 'application/json', 'content-type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({
            id: 1,
            jsonrpc: '2.0',
            method: 'starknet_getEvents',
            params: [
              {
                to_block: 'latest',
                address: '0x028a88bc21629b0f740b99046dbd096674e4cf89545efa6a6cd20b3e64ebb94c',
                chunk_size: 10,
                keys: [keyFilter]
              },
            ]
          })
        };
```

Now this only filters the events based on the `EVENT_NAME`, the keys in this case: (tokenId, creator) altho I’m passing to the keys parameter, they’re not being used for filtration. In the end I’m getting all the events with the event name/type `ERC1155CollectionLaunch`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question